# Order of $\epsilon$ Permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

From Prof. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra", here's a table for a group of permutations:

[image]

The "Order of Group Elements" chapter explains the concept of *order*. It explains that, per the above graph, $\alpha$'s order is 2 since $\alpha^{2}=\epsilon$.

What is $\epsilon$'s order? I'm thinking it's $[1..]$ where $1..$ means `1 to infinity`.

Please explain $\epsilon$'s order.

Comment: The order of an element is a single number.

Comment: Ah, per the chapter's definition: >If there exists a nonzero integer $m$ such at $a^{m}=\epsilon$, then the **order** of the element $a$ is defined to be the **least positive integer** $n$ such that $a^{n}=\epsilon$. So $\epsilon$'s order is **1**?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

The order of an element $'a'$ of a group is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $a^m = e$
in your case $\epsilon$ means $e$

$\Rightarrow$ the order of $\epsilon$ is $1$ because $\epsilon^1=\epsilon$